# R tidyverse to sumif based on function

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df like this:

**df1**

```
var1 var2 text
1    0    A 
1    1    A
0    1    B
```

So I would like to generate a two new ones based on a sumif function like this:

**df2**

```
text var1   var2
A    2      1
B    0      1
tot  2      4
```

And...

**df3**

```
text var1   var2
A    100    50
B    0      50
```

So the first one based on counts and the second one on column %

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `df2` :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% group_by(text) %>% summarise_all(sum) %>% janitor::adorn_totals('row')

#  text var1 var2
#     A    2    1
#     B    0    1
# Total    2    2
```

`df3`

```
df1 %>% group_by(text) %>% summarise_all(sum) %>% mutate_at(-1, ~./sum(.) * 100)

#  text   var1  var2
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A       100    50
#2 B         0    50
```